# Stuck: updating key/values in an instantiated JSON object without removing other characteristics

Tags: javascript, json, object, instance, key-value

I'm trying to update elements within an existing instance of an object.  When I do, some of what I presume are inherited characteristics do show up under **proto** in Chrome's Dev Tools.

```
//this is a Chrome Dev Tools view of the instantiated object I attempted to update/modify; 
//this is rejected by a later function I'm using in the xAPI tincan-min.js library

statement.target.definition.choices: Array(5)
0:
description: {en-US: "Apple"}
id: "kcContent.questions[3].answerChoices[0]"
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString() 
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()


//this is a Dev Tools view of a "placeholder" instantiated objects
1: TinCan.InteractionComponent   // how do I preserve the 'TinCan.InteractionComponent' characteristic when I update this instanced object?
description: {en-US: "pending"}
id: "pending"
__proto__:
LOG_SRC: "InteractionComponent"  
asVersion: ƒ (a)
getLangDictionaryValue: ƒ (a,b)
init: ƒ (a)
log: ƒ (a,b)
__proto__: Object


//these are additional "placeholder" objects--all of which have the "TinCan.InteractionComponent" prefix, which is what I'm losing when I try to update elements using the function below

2: TinCan.InteractionComponent {id: "pending", description: {…}}
3: TinCan.InteractionComponent {id: "pending", description: {…}}
4: TinCan.InteractionComponent {id: "pending", description: {…}}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

```
//This is the function I'm using to update the instantiated object:

    function populateStatementChoices(callback){ 
        console.log("Populating statement choices.");
        statement.target.definition.choices.forEach(function(item, index) {
            function setStatementChoiceID(num){
                //this updates the key/values but removes 'TinCan.InteractionComponent' from the object
                statement.target.definition.choices[num] = {
                    id:"kcContent.questions[" + choiceQuestionIndex + "].answerChoices[" + num + "]",
                    description:{"en-US":kcContent.questions[choiceQuestionIndex].answerChoices[num].choiceText},
                }
                setStatementChoiceID(index);
        });
        if (typeof callback === 'function'){
            callback();
        }
    };
```

Preserving the "TinCan.InteractionComponent" characteristics is what I cannot figure out.  Hoping someone has seen this before and can point me in the right direction.  Thanks for your time and attention; I appreciate it more than you know!

Comment: From what I understood of your question (it is very messy btw). JSON does not deal with functions. So you will lose your prototype or any function property in your object. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry for the mess and thanks for the help.  There is an array within this nested object (statement.target.definition.choices).  I have 5 "placeholders" with the TinCan.InteractionComponent characteristics.  I want to update the "id" and "description" of the existing objects *without* losing the TinCan.InteractionComponent characteristics.  I'm not sure what I am doing (or neglecting) in my function that causes my placeholders to lose the "TinCan.InteractionComponent" characteristics when I update 'id' and 'description' for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are losing the "TinCan.InteractionComponent" because you are setting the array position to be a new object.

```
statement.target.definition.choices = [ ..., ..., ..., ...]

//your code says, access the array position at number and assign (=) whatever is below to it.

statement.target.definition.choices[num] = {
                    id:"kcContent.questions[" + choiceQuestionIndex + "].answerChoices[" + num + "]",
                    description:{"en-US":kcContent.questions[choiceQuestionIndex].answerChoices[num].choiceText},
                }
```

First of all you should rewrite your function. You are not using forEach properly. I would recommend use of map because it does not mutate the array but for the sake of simplicity your code could be simplified to:

```
       function populateStatementChoices(callback){ 

            console.log("Populating statement choices.");
            statement.target.definition.choices.forEach(function(item, index) {

            item.id = "kcContent.questions[" + choiceQuestionIndex + "].answerChoices[" + index+ "]";
        item.description = { "en-US": kcContent.questions[choiceQuestionIndex].answerChoices[index].choiceText};
}
            if (typeof callback === 'function'){
                callback();
            }
        };
```

With that you should be good to go with the update without losing the other properties.

Comment: Thanks for helping out!  This was my first time using a forEach (which explains some of the mess).  I tried the simpler function you've proposed and it preserves the TinCan.InteractionComponent (yay!).  Unfortunately, I now seem to have a closure problem: when forEach finishes looping through the items, sets all of them to the item.id and item.description intended for the last element.

Comment: The inner function with the [num] parameter was my attempt to isolate/preserve the value of index at the time the function was called; this seemed to resolve the closure problem.

Comment: @KevanSizemore  If you like the answer upvote as the correct one. That is how you show gratitude around here :)

Comment: @KevanSizemore why would you try to preserve the index? Is there anything else that I am not seeing it ?

Comment: Reflecting on your comments & suggestions, I ended up going back and asking myself why I couldn't populate the array *before* instantiating the object.  As it turns out, this was a much simpler approach and it eliminated the issues I was experiencing with losing the TinCan.InteractionComponent or the closure problems which caused the most recent iteration value of 'id' and 'description' to be written into every element of the array.

Sometimes simpler is better.  Thank you @iwduarte!  I appreciate the help and you've taught me some new things.  All the best to you.